# Dominant pole approximation conditions for estimating settling time

Tags: control-theory

I have a second order system with the following step response: $$G_2(t) = a_o + a_1 e^{-t/\tau_1} + a_2 e^{-t/\tau_2}.$$

I would like to know what the settling time is through dominant pole approximation. Assuming the settling time, $t_s$, is reached at 95%, for a similar [first order system it is common to say](https://people-ece.vse.gmu.edu/%7Egbeale/ece_421/xmpl-421-1st-order-01.pdf) $t_s = 3\tau$. In the dominant pole approximation you can use the smallest pole (i.e. the largest time constant, $\tau$) to estimate the settling time, using the same formula as a first order system.

However, the conditions in which this approximation is valid were difficult to find without attempting my own mathematical proof.

I have seen one source say that the dominant pole approximation is only valid when: "Dominant pole time constant is 5x larger than other poles" for a generalised system ([with no proof](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece486/fa2021/documentation/lectures/slides/Lecture10A_DominantPoleApproximation.pdf)):

$\frac{A}{(s+p_0)(s+p_1)...(s+p_n)}$

For my system I assume there could be another condition ' $a_1/a_2 < threshold$ ' as well?

Or do I need to define an allowable region for a function with x and y axes, $a_1/a_2$ and $\tau_1/\tau_2$ since there are two conditions?

Thoughts?

Comment: As it is an approximation, we generally say, that the transient time is *almost* the same as of a first-order system is one pole is 10 ties larger. Or 5 times large - it changes just how accurate is our *almost*. If, however, you want a precise response, then consider the complete 2nd order system.

Comment: I think I will consider the overall system and just manually determine the settling time for each set of fitted parameters, saves any doubt of error. Thanks!